# Rails cron job run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a rails multitenant application.
And I have some branch listing in my app with branch_name and branch_email.
I want to run cronjob to send "good morning" email to each branch of each tenant.
I am using `Postgres` sql schemes as tenants.

Comment: Take a look at the `whenever` gem which automates cron jobs running a rails environment.

Comment: What is actually your question? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) gem as a background worker and use [Sidekiq Cron](https://github.com/ondrejbartas/sidekiq-cron) gem for scheduling.

Create a Worker to send email to each branch of each tenant.

create a file `app/workers/good_morning_email_worker.rb`

```
class GoodMorningEmailWorker
 include Sidekiq::Worker

 def perform
   # send your emails
 end
end
```

Then create a cron job from `rails console` to perform the worker every morning.

```
Sidekiq::Cron::Job.create(name: 'Email Worker - everyday @5am', cron: '0 5 * * *', class: 'GoodMorningEmailWorker')
```